# D-Link DWM-156 HSPA USB Modem doesn't work with SIM card inserted

Tags: ubuntu, usb, 64bit, modem, mobile

I have a D-Link DWM-156 HSPA modem, that I bought just a few days ago. The modem has drivers in its internal storage. There are Debian packages (.deb) for both i386 and amd64, so obviously I installed the amd64.deb using Software Center: `3g_modem_connect_D300_amd64.deb`. Then I did:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x2001 product=0x7d01
```

I have confirmed that the device switched to `usbserial` mode from `usb-storage` mode, as the product ID was a706 before. Although there are no commands like `usbdeviceswitchdlink` after installation.

But here is the thing, the device is detected and I get the mobile broadband options in the network menu **only** when a SIM card is **not** present in the modem. If a SIM card is present, the modem switches to `usbserial` mode but after that, there is no change in the network menu. I can't use my modem in Ubuntu at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this issue was fixed in Ubuntu 14.04. It also switches to USB modem mode automatically.

So, upgrading to 14.04 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem and have found a simple way to solve the issue. I have used the default `usb_modeswitch` itself to switch the storage mode to modem mode.

Double clicking will not install the `.deb` file for most of the users. So use `dpkg` command in terminal.

I have posted all the details with pictures so even beginers can easily solve the issue.

http://lawrencematthew.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/connecting-ubuntu-12-04-2-to-internet-using-d-link-dwm-156-3g3-75g-usb-modem/

Comment: I have done all that. The modem switches from cdrom to usbserial mode. The product ID is 0x7d01. But its doesn't show up as a mobile broadband device when a SIM Card is present. It shows up only when there is no SIM Card. I have used multiple SIM Cards too. Same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo` command along with usb modeswitch command.
It worked for a couple of people. If mode switch is success and sim card inserted then try `wvdial` to connect, or try `gnome-ppp` it has more better gui, more satisfactory.
Also definitly gives more options than default `network-manager-gnome`